# Is there any Office Suite or Application that can read Amipro .SAM files

Tags: libreoffice

Is there ANY program that supports reading AmiPro .SAM files. I have giving up hope for LibreOffice since I am still waiting for an email answer about it. But while I wait maybe somebody knows of another program that reads .sam files. in this case AmiPro 3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can forget open source alternatives. They never have and probably never will be able to: the format is closed and had not been open sourced.

There are 2 applications that can open these files:

- Microsoft Word 2000, 2003 or XP;
- IBM Lotus SmartSuite 97.

Word needs an [extra converter](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208863) that is not included with Word so I would advice to get a copy of IBM Lotus SmartSuite 97 and try to get it running in wine and save the files to a non-proprietary format. [Wine HQ](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1586) states the basics seem to work.

Comment: Hi Rinzwind. Thanks I already tested the converters for 2003 and 2007. both do not work. they mention it but do not really work. Tested not only on wine but on a Windows XP system and on a Windows 7 system. The only one left is the SmartSuite but I do not have that one. Also I am looking for open sourced apps. Office suite that are in the Ubuntu world that can do this.

Comment: I am afraid you can forget about open source alternatives... but you can find the smartsuite on the web ;)

Comment: Thanks Rinzwind I will still have some hope. I will look for it in the web ;)

Answer (score 0):

I used AmiPro a lot, but I import ONLY text now. I do simple text conversion into UTF-8:

```
timenow=$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S) 
sed -r '
s/^$/<\/p><p class="vo">/g;
s/<\\a>/á/g;
s/<\\d>/ä/g;
s/<\\h>/č/g;
s/<\\H>/Č/g;
s/<\\o>/ď/g;
s/<\\l>/ě/g;
s/<\\Z>/Ú/g;
s/<\\z>/Ú/g;
s/<\\i>/é/g;
s/<\\m>/í/g;
s/<\\x>/ř/g;
s/<\\X>/Ř/g;
s/<\\r>/ň/g;
s/<\\s>/ó/g;
s/<\\v>/ö/g;
s/<\/J>/Š/g;
s/<\/Z>/š/g;
s/<\/~>/ľ/g;
s/<\\X>/Ř/g;
s/<\\y>/ů/g;
s/<\/]>/ť/g;
s/<\\}>/ý/g;
s/<\/\^>/ž/g;
s/<\/N>/Ž/g;    
s/<:#[0-9,]*>//g

s/@([^@]*)@/<\/p><p class="\1">/g;
s/^\r$/<\p><p class="vo">/g;
' $1 >>jkamipro_konvertor$timenow.htm
firefox jkamipro_konvertor$timenow.htm &
```

May be of some help... :-)

Comment: I have about 35k amipro documents that I need to process and convert to libreoffice. I will test this week and let you know how it goes.